# Xamarin ImageSource converting to Byte[] or Stream

Tags: c#, image, api, xamarin

Im using the `CameraView` from Xamarin Community toolbox to capture a photo in the app I am helping develop, but I am struggling with sending the image to the api:

```
<views:CameraView
    HeightRequest="400"
    x:Name="cameraView"
    CaptureMode="Photo"
    CameraOptions="Back"
    FlashMode="On"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    MediaCaptured="cameraView_MediaCaptured">
</views:CameraView>
```

`Media_Caputured` returns an `ImageSource` which needs to be converted to a more useable datatype like `byte[]` or `Stream`

```
private async void cameraView_MediaCaptured(object sender, Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views.MediaCapturedEventArgs e)
{
    var image = e.Image;
    imageTaken = image;
    imageHolder.Source = image;
            
    fileContr.UploadFileAsync(image);
}
```

But I am having a diffucult time understanding how.

I tried storing it in a temporary Xamarin image field which I could not get to work and try converting it directly, I am sure I am missing a very simple function or method in the documenation somewhere.

Comment: You can check official doc definition: [MediaCapturedEventArgs Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.ui.views.mediacapturedeventargs?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk#definition).

Answer (score 2):

`MediaCapturedEventArgs` has an `ImageData` property that is a `byte[]`